# Does Florida's owner/builder exemption allow me to build a guest house and a main house on my lot?

Tags: real-estate, florida, construction-law

Florida statute 489.103(7) says that I'm allowed to build either a one family or two family residence as the owner-builder without a contractor's license.

I would like to build a guest house first and then live in it while building the main house but I'm unsure if I will be granted occupancy of the guest house if the whole "residence" is not yet completed (consisting of both buildings).

I'm also unsure if these two buildings count as a one or two-family residence or if the exemption is referring exclusively to duplexes and I will not be allowed to have two buildings.

How can I find the answer to these two questions?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the answer to these two questions?

The best bet is to look for a Lawyer specializing in Florida Construction Laws and specify your concerns during a client intake meeting.   Even if the firm you called does not specialize in your area of law, you can also ask for a referral to a firm that is better.  You are likely not the first person calling about this branch of the law and they likely know a firm or a lawyer who does work in this branch who can better help.